# Child component doesn't inherit input but the other do

Tags: angular, typescript, inheritance, extends

I have a component that I've "Almost" copied pasted from my other component.

My first component the inheritance works with the input, but not the 2nd one.

Then I get an error that says

```
Can't bind to 'anInput' since it isn't a known property of 'my-copied-component'.


<my-copied-component
    [anInput]="someInputValue" <--- ERROR
>
</my-copied-component>

<my-original-component
    [anInput]="someInputValue" <--- Works fine
>
</my-original-component>
```

implementation:

```
export class MyCopiedComponent extends MyComponentsBase implements OnInit {
```

base implementation:

```
export class MyComponentsBase implements OnInit {

@Input() public anInput: string;
```

I have super() in constructor.

Comment: Could we see more code from `MyComponentsBase` & `MyCopiedComponent`? Specifically the component decoration above them.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Ensure that you have declared the new component in your module -

```
@NgModule({
  declarations: [MyCopiedComponent]
})
export class SomeModule {}
```

Comment: this was the answer, thanks.

I'm new to Angular so I did not know this would affect it.

Comment: Mark it as accepted then ;) You're welcome, happy to help!

Comment: I will in 7 minutes, can't until then :P

Comment: Yeah I wanted to comment but I'm not allowed under 50rep. Edited with some code now!